# Why is Array * referencing, and not copying, values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I want to duplicate a hash using the same keys but different values. I coded up the following snippet, and encountered something I didn't expect:

```
hsh = {:foo => 'foo', :bar => 'bar'}

hsh_copy = Hash[hsh.keys.zip([[]] * hsh.length)] # => {:foo=>[], :bar=>[]}
hsh_copy[:foo] << 1
hsh_copy[:bar] << 2

hsh_copy # => {:foo=>[1, 2], :bar=>[1, 2]}
```

It seems that instead of copying the nested array when using the `*` operator, it just continues to reference the first array.

I'd be very happy if someone could explain *why* this is happening. Additionally, a better way of duplicating the hash would be appreciated, but I'm more concerned with understanding why `*` doesn't work as expected here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Array#*` copied the elements of the array, it would break when used on arrays with non-copyable elements (which includes, among others, numbers), which would not be desirable.

As for how to do what you want to do: Replace `hsh.keys.zip([[]] * hsh.length)` with `hsh.map {|k,v| [k, []] }`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer--it seems the ruby documentation is somewhat misleading, as it explicitly says "copies." With the same logic though, why wouldn't the following code replace all `['a']` with `['d']`, and not just the first? `arr = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']] * 3; arr[0] = ['d']`. And then this: `arr = [[], [], []] * 3; arr[0] = {}`?

Comment: @vonconrad: Because in those cases you're not mutating the first array element, you're setting a new one. It's the same reason why `a = "a"; b = a; b.replace("b")` changes both `a` and `b`, while `a = "a"; b = a; b = "b"` does not.

Comment: @vonconrad: I don't think the documentation is misleading, though it's an understandable misreading. The docs say "copies *of self*" — that is, the method copies the array *n* times. Nowhere does it say the items in the array are copied. The trouble is that you're assuming a deep copy, but the method actually does a shallow copy (which is the default for array copy methods in most languages).

Answer (score 1):

The `*` operator concatenates copies of the array together to meet the new length.

If an array element references an object, when it is duplicated a new array element is in fact created, but it's a new array element that references the same object.

For example:

```
irb(main):012:0> ([[]] * 3).map { |e| e.object_id }
```

=> [2149128060, 2149128060, 2149128060]

In your case, you could just create new elements with `.map` and let Ruby create a new object with [] each time,  but for a general solution, start with:

```
irb(main):013:0> ([[]] * 3).map { |e| e.clone.object_id }
```

=> [2149106700, 2149106660, 2149106640]